# NSDocument does not receive printOperationWithSettings

Tags: cocoa, swift, printing, nsdocument

I need some help how to debug my NSDocument subclass that do not receive a call to printOperationWithSettings.

I implement a Document-Subclass

```
class Document: NSDocument {
...
```

and overwrite the printOperationWithSettings method:

```
    override func printOperationWithSettings(printSettings: [NSObject : AnyObject], error outError: NSErrorPointer) -> NSPrintOperation? {
NSLog(" ******************  printOperationWithSettings")
    return nil
}
```

But this method is never called. readFromData, dataOfType, makeWindowControllers, ... works ok, but if i print, the printing preference panel will open and the print job does its work without asking printOperationWithSettings.

I did'n know what I am doing wrong, but more frustrating is that I don't know how to debug this. No Idea where to look and how to solve this.

I need to print a special view, - not that one that is currently on the screen, because the user can hide some information that i definitely want to have on paper.

Thanks for any help or idea where i can look and dig on this problem.

ps

Answer (score 3):

how are you starting the print operation? That method should be called if you start it with **-printDocument:**, while it won't be called if you invoke **-print:**

Comment: Start the Operation with Apple-P shortcut.

Comment: Make sure that the menu item corresponding to that shortcut is sending the -printDocument: selector. If you created the project using the document-based application template, it should already be correct. Otherwise you might need to change it.